# Rails force object to save even when validation fails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation

I want to force a save of an object even when a validation fails. I tried doing this

```
te.save(:validate => false)
```

However, this did not seem to work. What is the right way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's the way according to the source of [`save_with_validation`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveResource/Validations.html#method-i-save_with_validation).

Are you sure it's not saved? Maybe you have database constraints which keep you from saving your object.

Have you checked your logs looking for INSERTs or UPDATEs?